# Combining SQL statements into one

Tags: sql

**I have the task to read data of two tables which requires several SQL statements, with only 1 query.**

I know that this is possible and i have done some research on that matter but this sadly did not help me as i had no clue how to apply this to my problem.

I believe it is not too complex but because of my lack of SQL experience it's quite a challenge for me.

For understanding purposes i would like to know how to combine these three statements into one.

*I have two tables. "PEmpl" and "Department" and i have the value ID.*

PEmpl has the columns: "DepartmentID" and "PEmplID"

Department has the columns: "DepartmentID" "DepartmentName" and "FatherDepID"

I have the EmployerID and want to find out to what departments he has permissions so i came up with these 3 statements.
(I already programmed it working in C# with these querys, but sadly the task was to do it in only 1 query and no c#)*

```
SELECT DepartmentID
FROM PEmpl
WHERE PEmplID = @ID <-- the  ID i have

SELECT DepartmentName
FROM Department
WHERE DepartmentID = @DepartmentID <- The DepID i got from the last query

SELECT DepartmentName
FROM Department
WHERE FatherDepID = @DepartmentID <- same ID as last querys
```

But i have no idea how to combine these into 1. I hope that someone can give me some clue about this. I dont expect to get the finished answer but a nudge into the right direction would be appreciated.

This is what i programmed in C#. I have the Person and it's ID and there you see that he has permission for "Musterfirma Gmbh" and because this is the father department of the others, he has also permission for those.

[image]

PS: I hope i explained it understandable. If not let me know and i will try to rephrase it :)

Comment: Post your code as a block of code, not an image.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I have understood correctly your question (pls post some sample data).  I think you could try something like following query.
I use only one join with a OR condition, and add a column to identify if father, direct or both deps.
I used "aliases" of tables (A for PEmpl  and B for Department  to simplify reading the query)

```
SELECT B.DepartmentName
      , CASE WHEN A.DepartmentID=B.DepartmentID AND A.DepartmentID=B.FatherDepID THEN 'B' /* both */
             WHEN A.DepartmentID=B.DepartmentID THEN 'D' /* "direct" dep */
             ELSE 'F'  /* father */                              
        END AS GR  /* case updated thanks to Caleth suggestion */
FROM  PEmpl A
INNER JOIN Department B ON A.DepartmentID=B.DepartmentID OR A.DepartmentID=B.FatherDepID
WHERE A.PEmplID = @ID
```

If you need only records without (possible) "repetitions" of departments, you can remove GR column and use DISTINCT after SELECT.

Comment: You need to invert you `WHEN`s to allow the `ELSE` to ever match

Answer (score 0):

Like this maybe

```
SELECT 
DepartmentID as dep0
FROM PEmpl 
    LEFT JOIN Department as dep1 on (dep0.DepartmentID = dep1.DepartmentID)
    LEFT JOIN Department as dep2 on (dep0.DepartmentID = dep2.DepartmentID)
WHERE PEmplID = @ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for this

```
SELECT
  A.DepartmentID,
  A.PEmplID,
  B.DepartmentID,
  B.DepartmentName, 
  B.FatherDepID
FROM PEmpl A
  INNER JOIN Department B
    ON A.DepartmentID = B.DepartmentID
    AND A.PEmplID = @ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, if it isn't working, fix joining columns, and check out `joins` that's what you need

```
  SELECT d2.DepartmentId, d2.DepartmentName 
  FROM PEmpl e
       JOIN Department d1 on e.DepartmentID = d1.DepartmentID
       JOIN Department d2 on d2.FatherDepID = d1.DepartmentID
  WHERE e.PEmplID = @ID   <-- your ID
```

Comment: Don't just blindly `SELECT *`, find the column(s) required

Comment: Can you explain what d2/d1 abd e are?

Comment: @MansNotHot it's table alias, as you are joining tables on itself, you have to set alias of the table, that way SQL understand from which data set you want to pull data from, also alias is used instead of writing `PEmpl.DepartmentId` or any other column you wish to select, you just go for alias `e.DepartmentId`, that way it's easier for you to write it up, also if you use something better then `e` it improve readability of query

Answer (score 0):

You need a `JOIN`, or possibly many.

```
WITH Deps AS (
-- This finds the parent departments. We have two copies of the same DepartmentID to have the same shape results as below
    SELECT DepartmentName, DepartmentID AS Link, DepartmentID
        FROM Departments 
-- Combine results from two SELECT clauses (without duplicates)
    UNION
-- This will find all the child departments, all the child's children, etc
    SELECT child.DepartmentName, child.DepartmentID AS Link, parent.DepartmentId
        FROM Departments AS child
-- We can join on the results we are selecting, to follow links
        JOIN Deps AS parent ON child.FatherDepID = parent.Link )
SELECT DepartmentName
-- To add any other columns from Departments, be sure to include them in both SELECT clauses above
    FROM PEmpl
    JOIN Deps ON PEmpl.DepartmentID = Deps.DepartmentID
```